What is it called when you have a hobby where you're good enough at to impress others but you yourself know you're only beginning?
Like the title says, I'm looking for the theorem or the effect that makes you feel incompetent compared to a master (let's take playing music for example) but good enough that others that aren't in said hobby find it impressive.
I thought of the Dunning-Kruger effect but it's not exactly that.

Are you referring to the impostor syndrome ?

What you are describing is the exact opposite of the Dunning-Kruger effect. The Dunning-Kruger effect describes those who perceive themselves to be expert on some topic but in fact are nowhere close. You are describing those who are overly critical of themselves while others see them as very good on some topic. Good to excellent home cooks, for example, often exhibit this latter behavior. They can sense the slightest imperfections. It still tastes darn good. Bad home cooks often exhibit the Dunning-Kruger effect. They think their cooking is excellent. Everyone avoids their dinner invites.

I agree with @Graffito -- imposter syndrome.

Wisdom. Knowing what you don't know is called wisdom.

I think the person experiencing Impostor syndrome is often proficient in their area. The person in question may be a total beginner in their area, so their reservations as to their competence may totally be justified both in their own mind and from others' perspective.

I would call it being realistic.

How about talented amateur?

@DavidHammen There are two primary and complementary aspects of the DK effect. One is that limited skill/knowledge people overrate their abilities, the other is that people with better than average skill/knowledge underrate their abilities relative to the average person. The latter is similar to what the OP is describing but not exactly the same.

@JohnGordon: or semi-pro.

There's a great Peanuts cartoon where Snoopy, after dispatching a challenger on the tennis court, remarks "That is the difference between a professional and a merely competent amateur"

In the land of the blind, the one-eyed man is king. Per Wiktionary:

Even someone with limited abilities or opportunities is dominant over, and considered special by, those who have even fewer abilities and opportunities; the value of any ability depends on its prevalence.


Very nice, this has the added layer that the one-eyed not only can see better than the blind but is also much better at judging the difference between a one-eyed man and two-eyed man that a blind person would be.

This is so far off the mark (that of the understanding of self) that I hardly need to elaborate. And it's a lot of what's wrong with phrase and single-word requests on this site.

@Robusto I don't get what's off the mark about this answer to the question, so perhaps it's not that obvious to some people. Can you elaborate?

@justhalf My thoughts exactly.

@justhalf: Like Robusto, I find this rather off the mark — the meaning matches when explained literally, but the typical traditional usage and connotations don’t fit at all.  This proverb connotes dominance and often arrogance of the “one-eyed man” over the “blind” in some sort of struggle, and emphasises that competition much more than how they might compare to others elsewhere.  OP’s description by contrast emphasises the beginner as quite self-aware, and comparing themself to “masters”, while the people unduly impressed aren’t themselves competing in the same arena at all.

@PLL I think you're reading too much into a popular proverb often used in situations like the one in the original poster's question. Where does this bit "connotes dominance and often arrogance" come from? Any trusted source or your own interpretation?

@user405662: I agree my explanation is a bit heavy-handed — I think that’s inevitable when trying to explicitly spell out some implicit and slightly subtle connotations.  It’s just from my own experience of the usage, but searching for examples online, they pretty much all fit the characterisation as being more about winning or being dominant in some kind of competitive situation, e.g. here,  [cont’d]

[cont’d] here, and here.  If your impression is to the contrary, can you say what that’s based on in turn?

You are a big fish in a small pond.

Being a big fish in a small pond refers to a setting where you are
more powerful/important/influential than your, rather small, peer
group. [A person whose expertise/ability is probably overestimated by
the laypeople around them.]

[Gaurav Kaumar; LinkedIn]

I'd say that is applicable only if the hobby gives the practitioner more influence in some social group.  It clearly does not fit the question if the ‘pond’ is understood to mean fellow hobbyists.

But OP specifies 'you're good enough ... to impress others'; totally separating 'impressing' from 'influencing' is something you'd have to justify. Dictionary.com has 'impress:
to affect deeply or strongly in mind or feelings; influence in opinion:

My friends are impressed by my math-art, but it doesn't make me ‘a big fish’.

It makes you a big math fish in the small math pond.

Big fish, small pond (or vice versa) is used in a different context to having apparent skills that lack in depth (which is what OP is asking about). Big fish, small pond refers to someone who settles for relative superiority to their immediate surroundings as opposed to measuring themselves on a larger scale (where they will be relatively smaller). This would only apply to OP's scenario if the intent was to wow others without intending to pursue the skill beyond its initial wow factor.

This is so far off the mark (that of the understanding of self) that I hardly need to elaborate. And it's a lot of what's wrong with phrase and single-word requests on this site.

Two more options:
Impressive to the untrained eye is rather an idiom than a full expression, but seems to capture the essence of the intent quite well. Although it seems to get used mostly for the opposite meaning, namely when something looks unimpressive to the uninitiated.
And, in case you want to highlight that despite there being quite some road ahead, there has been progress, one could go with a beginner among masters, but a master among beginners. Not that good a fit to the original request, but related enough to my ears to include it here.

You know enough to be dangerous.
A little knowledge is a dangerous thing.
When somebody has basic competency in doing something, but is not an expert, so he or she can potentially make mistakes that might break something.

This doesn't really communicate the idea of other people being impressed with your knowledge. I know enough about law to be a danger to myself and others, but that doesn't mean that I'd wow the average lay person.

Impostor syndrome seems close. However, it suggests the person experiencing it is more skilled than they believe, and are being overcritical of themselves.
From wikipedia:

Impostor syndrome, also known as impostor phenomenon or impostorism, is a psychological experience of intellectual and professional fraudulence.[1] One source defines it as "the subjective experience of perceived self-doubt in one's abilities and accomplishments compared with others, despite evidence to suggest the contrary"


No, this definitely doesn't fit. Imposter syndrome makes no reflection on actual skillset, and it's as likely to afflict the most skilled person on earth as it is the newest learner. And I say that as a 20+ year industry veteran who still wonders sometimes why people put so much faith in my abilities...

In that situation, I'd probably refer to myself as a journeyman. As in "journeyman carpenter" or "journeyman mouth harpist".
Its got a traditional technical meaning, as tradesman who has completed their apprenticeship, but is not at the level of a master. However, that kind of formal trade apprenticeship/guild arrangement is uncommon now, so its more often just used to describe someone who can do the work of a craft acceptably, but is not at the level of a master craftsman.
Since you used the term "master" in the question itself, and basically described the relative level of a journeyman, IMHO this is The Answer.

I'm not sure there is a term for exactly what you describe.  I think the problem is that such a term would only be utilized by someone with a third person omniscient point of view. That precludes everything short of fiction and subjective essays.
Imposter syndrome alone is an relative description--you feel incompetent compared to another. And while it may describe how you feel about yourself, it does not describe how others feel about you. You could very well be a master, but not feel it. It doesn't speak to the fact your audience is impressed.
There is a term called competency porn which describes the phenomenon of taking pleasure as you watch someone who is good at a task, do well at that task. It doesn't capture the feeling of impostership, though.
The POVs of both you and the audience would need to be known and synthesized by a third party in order to have cause to then accurately describe the situation.

That happened to me quite a bit when I was in college.  I called it "involuntary oneupsmanship."  Thinking of that British comedy (with Alistair Sim?) that popularized the idea of oneupsmanship.
